# Excel VBA - Pass Button Caption to Button Click

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a spread sheet that creates and destroys a number of buttons using the method below.  123456 represents a sales order that I would like to look up using "VIEW_SO"

```
Dim btn As Button
Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(cell.left, cell.top , cell.width, cell.height)
With btn
    .OnAction = "VIEW_SO"
    .caption = "SO=123456"
    .name = "SO123456"
End With
```

This works great.  The problem lies in what I want VIEW_SO to change its behavior based on the sales number.  Is there a way to get the button name or caption within the routine?  Below is what I want to do:

```
Public Sub View_SO (CAPTION as String)
    'I need to extract 123456 based on which button exists and pass 
    '   it to the subroutine
    v = split(CAPTION,"=",2)
    'Go do stuff with v(1)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.Caller` will give you the name of the button

Comment: Works perfectly.  This entire method does break down when 2 buttons have the same number.  The second button gets auto-named "Button ###"

Comment: @DavidFolkner - sincr you're adding and naming the buttons dynamically, you should be able to check if there's already an existing button wth the same name: if you need two buttons which do the same thing, name the second one using (e.g.) an incrementing suffix which you can strip off in the click handler.